# Oracle Regex_replace to delete a pattern and following 3 characters

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I'm trying to do the following operation. I have many lines of data that needs to be edited to delete a part of a string. This string contains a pattern B0ExxB+, where 'x' could be any character or number.

- Input example (string) : `'1SX8+B0DSUB+B0E0LB+B0FMAB+B0G0KB'`
- Desired output : `'1SX8+B0DSUB+B0FMAB+B0G0KB'`

I use the *REGEXP_REPLACE* operation.
have two strategies to accomplish the operation:

1. Known the pattern B0E apply more regex operators to pick also the 4 following characters after the pattern, and then replace them by nothing.

   - Main idea.

   `update rx3qtxin xn set cin.cin_value = REGEXP_REPLACE (cin.cin_value, '\SB0E', '') where cin.id = 500228;`

That deletes the pattern, OK.
I've tried with adding as many ? after the pattern but it delete any other part of the string.

2. Known left pattern (**B0E**) and right pattern (**B+**) delete where both patterns are matched and the content between them.

   - No idea how to apply that idea in regex.*

Comment: Please rephrase your question by showing clear input with expected output.

Comment: Maybe `REGEXP_REPLACE(col, 'B0E[[:alnum:]]{2}B[+]', '')`?

Comment: What's with the `\S` in the regular expression in your attempt? There is no mention of it in the problem description.

Comment: Jorge, do you mean you want to avoid matching `BBExxB+`? Try `REGEXP_REPLACE('1SX8+B0DSUB+B0E0LB+B0FMAB+B0G0KB', '(^|\+)B0E[[:alnum:]]{2}B\+(B0E[[:alnum:]]{2}B\+)*', '\1')` then (it also matches consecutive occurrences).

Comment: After your edit, does it mean my first suggestion worked for you?

Comment: @mathguy \S-->matches a non-whitespace character. I thought i need to put before the pattern a regex operator, like \S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question mark is a placeholder for a single character in Unix ("wildcard character"). In regular expressions, for the same task we use the dot (period). The question mark (in regular expression) just makes the subexpression it applies to optional. It won't help you with your task.

You need something like

```
regexp_replace(col, 'B0E..B\+')
```

Note that the "plus sign" must be escaped, since unescaped it is a metacharacter.

Comment: Works perfect. I thought i need a regex operator before the pattern.